# The second function of jQuery hover() does not work on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, hover

With the following jQuery code, when touch device users touch the `div` element, the hover effect appears. And after they touch a blank area, the hover effect should disappear.

```
$('div').hover(
    function() { $(this).text('hover effect appears') },
    function() { $(this).text('') }
);
```

That works fine on Android OS. But on iOS, the hover effect does not disappear.

Please see the [demonstration on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx78m7th/).

Comment: @A.Wolff I saw the issue on iPad.

Comment: So i guess because on iPad the mouseleave event isn't fired because you touch unfocusable element. By blanck area, do you mean the `body`? If so, try by setting `<body tabindex="-1">`. Be aware, i currently cannot test anything on iPad

Comment: @A.Wolff I just tried `<body tabindex="-1">` and the issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjh42/fm4Ly2Lo/). Tested in both Safari and Chrome (latest versions) on iPad Air 2 with iOS 9.3.5, and it functions as expected.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hover"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('div.hover').hover(
    function() { $(this).text('hover effect appears') },
    function() { $(this).text('') }
);

$('div.hover').on('tap', function() {
    $('div.hover').text('hover effect appears');
    return false;
});

$('body').on('tap', function(e) {
    $('div.hover').text('');
});
```

CSS:

```
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
}

html, body {
      height: 100%;
}

div.hover {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Alternatively, if you would also like the "hover" effect to disappear when your user touches the `<div>` again, you can use the following `tap` event instead of the above `tap` event:

```
$('div.hover').on('tap', function() {
    var $div = $('div.hover');

    if($div.text().length) {
        $div.text('');
    }
    else {
        $div.text('hover effect appears');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That works in jsFiddle. However, since the jQuery Mobile script wraps all child elements of the `body` with `<div class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" data-role="page" data-url="/mjh42/fm4Ly2Lo/show/" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 438px;"></div>`, would it cause unwanted behaviors if I use it on an existing website?

Comment: That's coming from jsfiddle.net, not jQuery Mobile. `mjh42/fm4Ly2Lo` is part of the fiddle's URL.

Comment: I know the url is jsFiddle's url. What I mean is that, does `<div class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" data-role="page" data-url="......" tabindex="0" style="min-height: ......px;"></div>`, which is added by the jQuery Mobile script, cause any unwanted behavior to existing websites?

Comment: What I mean is that the entire wrapping `<div>` is coming from jsfiddle.net, not just its `data-url` attribute. That `<div>` has nothing to do with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: The entire wrapping `<div>` is coming from the jQuery Mobile script. jsFiddle does not add that.

Comment: I have a properly-functioning stand-alone html page I put together that replicates the fiddle, and there is no wrapping `<div>`. If it was coming from jQuery mobile, my standalone page would have the `<div>` as well.

Comment: Please use developer tools such as Firebug to inspect the page. The  jQuery Mobile script does add the wrapping `div`.

Comment: That is of course what I have done, and I see no `<div>` on the standalone page.

Comment: Could you please let me see the standalone page?

Comment: Sure. Here's a dropbox link, but it won't run directly, you'll have to download it and run it locally: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrv2keky773cfvd/39793408.html?dl=0

Comment: Thanks. I just checked it, and saw this javascript error in console: `TypeError: a.event.props is undefined`. So in the standalone page, the jQuery Mobile is unable to execute due to the javascript error. Could you try fixing the error and then test again?

Comment: Just noticed that myself.  Use `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js` for jQuery instead of the 3.1.0 link, seems there are some compatibility issues. And now I see a similar `<div>`. Sorry, but I don't know what effect that will have on your site.